# Make iOS 7 (iPhone 5 size) app supportable to iOS 8 (iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have working app for iOS 7 but now I want my app will support for iOS 8 also. I searched a lot but not getting any proper link. My problem is if I want to add iOS 8 support then my old app is designed using xib and Xcode 4.6 so is it necessary to design all files using storyboard to make dynamic size which apple suggest or else what is the another way. 
    Also I’m having all images for iPhone 5 size so for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus I need to add another images or I can continue with the same.

Comment: it's better to use Autolayout or Auto resizing property.

Comment: Thanks for reply  PradhyumanSinh . You mean I need to start design all files using storyboad ??

Comment: No, you do not need to use Storyboard. Autolayout works with UIViews. You can use your old xib based interface. Have you tried compiling it and seeing how it works?